# Using NamedTemporaryFile

Tags: python, temporary-files

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.shp').name as tmp_shp:
    df.to_file(tmp_shp)
```

In code above, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

How can I use a named temporary file using with statement? and since `tmp_shp` is just a path, does it still stay available outside of `with`?

Comment: Why are you trying to use the file's `name` attribute as a context manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `name` attribute is a string; trying to access it in the `with` statement makes it the managed resource (and `str` has no concept of context management). You need to manage the `NamedTemporaryFile` itself, and access the `name` as needed:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.shp') as tmp_shp:
    df.to_file(tmp_shp.name)  # Access .name here, assuming you need a str
```

If `to_file` accepts file-like objects (I can't find docs for such a method), you'd avoid using `.name` at all (in either line).

**Update:** Because you're on Windows, [you can't actually open a file opened by `NamedTemporaryFile` with `delete=True` (the default) until the `NamedTemporaryFile` is closed](https://bugs.python.org/issue14243) (which means you can't use any data written to that file handle, since it's deleted, and introduces a race condition even if using it solely to generate a unique name; the file is deleted at that point, so you're really just creating a new file, but someone else might race you to creating that file later). Best I can suggest here is to using it without deletion support to get a unique name, wrapping it to force deletion yourself, e.g.:

```
tmp_shp = None
try:
    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.shp', delete=False) as tmp_shp:

        df.to_file(tmp_shp.name)  # Access .name here, assuming you need a str

        ... do any other stuff with the file ...
finally:
    if tmp_shp is not None:
        os.remove(tmp_shp.name)
```

Yeah, it's ugly. There aren't a lot of good options here; `NamedTemporaryFile` is fundamentally broken on Windows.

Comment: thank @ShadowRanger. I get this error `*** RuntimeError: Failed to open C:\Users\rk\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpz5c2fvlg.shp`

Comment: @user308827: Oh, ugh, you're on Windows. There are... [issues](https://bugs.python.org/issue14243)... with `NamedTemporaryFile` on Windows. Short version is you can't actually open it with most programs unless you pass `delete=False` when you create it (which removes most of the point), or you're using it solely to make a unique name (and close it before anyone else uses it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You've misunderstood (or at least misrepresented) the issue thread. What the issue is talking about is that you can't *reopen* the file underlying a NamedTemporaryFile by name until the file is closed, and that reopening requires `delete=False` to prevent the file from auto-deleting on close. Your answer currently implies that a NamedTemporaryFile with delete=True can be opened after closing it; it can't be, as the file is gone by that point.

Comment: @user2357112: Given that the API in question operates on the file *name*, it *is* trying to reopen it. I was pointing out that the only way to "reopen" it with `delete=True` is to close it (which deletes it in the process), then reopen that name (given the API uses names, it's presumably capable of creating the file); as mentioned, closing/deleting it before using the name introduces a race in which someone else might use the name. My example code which avoids the issue uses `delete=False` to avoid the race, but in exchange, has to reimplement automatic deletion from scratch, which is a pain.

Comment: Your original wording didn't convey that you would be creating a new file if you tried to open the file after closing with `delete=True`. Your new wording... well, it's kind of confusingly structured, but it does at least convey you'd be creating a new file. (Also, apparently you *can* reopen a NamedTemporaryFile before closing with `delete=False`, so either the OP in the issue report was wrong, or things have changed since then. I initially thought this was an error in your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

You use the name attribute as a context manager. Try:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.shp') as tmp_shp:
    df.to_file(tmp_shp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use with statement for `NamedTemporaryFile` itself but not its `name` attribute.

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.shp') as tmp_file:
    df.to_file(tmp_file)  # As temp_file is a file object, I think to_file should work?
```

And as the official doc, `tmp_file` will be deleted outside of `with` unless you pass `delete=False` to `NamedTemporaryFile`.

That means you should `with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.shp', delete=False) as tmp_file:`